# Spring MVC DelegatingFilterProxy: get bean from Servlet WebApplicationContext (not Root WebApplicationContext) to separate Spring Security contexts

Tags: spring, spring-security

Spring Web MVC provides an ability to have a hierarchy of application contexts: one Root WebApplicationContext and multiple Servlet WebApplicationContexts
[image]

This feature allows to create real independent contexts in one application.

But is it possible to do the same with Spring Security configuration?

SecurityFilterChain works under the DelegatingFilterProxy. To initialize DelegatingFilterProxy we need provide a filter name (springSecurityFilterChain) of a bean that is a part of initialization process of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (my Spring Security version is still 5.4.5 and DispatcherServlet is being initialized via web.xml, no Spring Boot)

Because Spring Security configuration is part of Servlet WebApplicationContext we get the expected error

```
ERROR [/] - Exception starting filter [springSecurityFilterChain]
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available
```

Does it mean that there is no way to have separate Spring Security configurations for each Servlet WebApplicationContext and it can be initialized and configured only in the Root WebApplicationcontext?

Comment: You can have multiple filters delegating to a different chain. But you have to ask yourself is that really what you want? Generally Spring Security can be configured globally even for multiple servlets/paths.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to have multiple independent Spring contexts in one application. Spring MVC allows to do it via having multiple Servlet WebApplicationContexts -> having multiple DispatcherServlets. And it would be nice to have own Spring Security configuration for each of these servlets

Comment: Trust me I know how it works. However not sure if you really want to split the security configuration? Why would you it is still one application (regardless of the multiple servlets). What is different that you need different fiters for it, yu can simply create one config for security (reusing the common parts) to differ on paths.

Comment: It is monolith application. It can have different features and domains like: public and internal APIs. Every feature can have own authorisation mechanism. By changing security configuration for feature A I'd like not affect configuration for feature B. And since we have multiple Servlet WebApplicationContexts domain definition for autorisation is stored in this context, so we can't move it to the root context.

Comment: still it is one application and not having a shared security implementation will lead to weird issues (especially if you cross boundaries or if a user needs access to different parts). Nonetheless as stated you can define multiple delegating filters, which delegate to different configuration. You can even bind those filter definitions to specific servlets.

Comment: For sure there can be common filters. But the main question if it is possible somehow to instantiate those DelegatingFilterProxies in the Servlet contexts? Seems that it can be done only in the Root context

Comment: With a bit of work. Each servlet registeres, by default, its applicationcontext in the servletcontext under a generated name `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT[servlet-name]`. You can use the `contextAttribute` property to specify the name of the property in he servlet context that holds the application context to use to retrieve the beans. If you set that to the same it will use the application context of the servlet to retrieve the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DelegatingFilterProxy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html#setContextAttribute(java.lang.String)) by default will use the root `WebApplicationContext` to lookup the filter. However you can specify through the `contextAttribute` property which attribute in the `ServletContext` holds the `WebApplicationContext` to use for configuration.

By default the [`FrameworkServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html) (the main class for the `DispatcherServlet` and friends) will expose its `WebApplicationContext` under a generated key in the `ServletContext`.

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher1</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Given the above servlet definition it will expose the context under `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher1`. You can use this to configure the `DelegatingFilterProxy`.

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>dispatcher1-security-filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher1</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name> dispatcher1-security-filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher1</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

With this filter definition it will use the `WebApplicationContext` from the `dispatcher1` servlet to configure security. It will look for a security filter named `dispatcher1-security-filter` in that context (you can specify the name while configuring security). If you want to stick with the default you will need to add an `init-param` for the `targetBeanName` property and set it to `springSecurityFilterChain`.

Drawback of this approach is however that the context might not be shared and different security configurations for authetication (or authorization) might be in conflict with each other.